# How does selecting new guard relays work?

Tags: attacks, guard, guard-node, dos

I've been told guards are selected when a client first connects to the Tor network and used until they *disappear*.

What constitutes *disappearing*?
Do all guards need to disappear (and then the whole set is replaced) or just one (and only that one is replaced)?

Would it be possible to get selected as a target's guard by DoS'ing random guards until you get chosen?

Comment: Where were you told guards are used until they "disappear", this isn't true? And yes, it's possible to denial of service a guard as a discovery mechanism. It's known as the [*"Sniper Attack"*](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/new-tor-denial-service-attacks-and-defenses).

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/since-what-version-number-is-first-tor-ip-address-unchanged/10612#10612 this answers guard rotation, the sniper attack is also covered elsewhere too.

Comment: Well I wasn't "told" exactly, I heard it in a talk.

Roger Dingledine said it at 11:30 of his Defcon 16 talk: Security and 
Anonymity Vulnerabilities in Tor: Past, Present, Future
 https://media.torproject.org/video/Defcon16-Roger_Dingledine-Sec_Anonymity_Vulns_in_Tor.m4v

The exact quote is ``The idea is every client picks 3 or 4 entry nodes. Three or four Tor servers as her first hop always and she sticks with those 3 or 4 until they disappear''

Comment: Ah, defcon 16 is quite some time ago. See the other answer I linked above for what guard rotation looks like more recently, and my answer to a question about guard lifetimes here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/guard-nodes-how-long-is-too-long

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it might contain the information I need